# Scrollable div inside fullpage.js section not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullpage.js, scrollable

I am using fullpage.js I have created 11 section using this but for last section I have more content which is inside div, but the div is not scrolling inside section.

```
<div class="section" id="section10">
    <div class="img_b">  <span class="icon icon--arrow icon--arrow-up" id="moveSectionUp"></span>
        <div class="intro10">
            <h1 class="sec10_h">10. There are plenty of great fresh dog food brands.</h1>
            <h4 class="sec10_sub_h">So, which dog food brand is right for your pup? There are several great options.</h4>
            <img class="nom_nom" src="https://static.insiderenvy.com/images/2021/06/28084619/Rectangle-17-12.jpg">
            <h2 class="nom_h">Nom Nom</h2>
            <p class="sec10_cont">Nom Nom offers a custom formula made for your dog based on their age, weight, body condition, and any health conditions. Their dog food was developed alongside an in-house veterinarian specializing in pet nutrition. NomNom even offers a Microbiome Testing Kit to learn more about your pet’s specific gut needs, which gives you a comprehensive analysis of your pet’s gut and what that means for their health. With NomNom, you’re not just getting delicious, healthy food, you’re also given the option to participate in cutting-edge pet health technology. And even if you’re just looking for some chow for your pet pup, you can rest assured that this focus on science extends to every part of NomNom’s philosophy, right down to what ends up in your dog’s bowl.  </p>

            <img class="nom_nom" src="https://static.insiderenvy.com/images/2021/06/29080744/Rectangle-17-13.jpg">
            <h2 class="nom_h">The Farmer’s Dog</h2>
            <p class="sec10_cont">Like NomNom, The Farmer’s Dog offers gently cooked fresh food to preserve as many nutrients as possible. Their food also comes ready-to-serve, in convenient pre-portioned packs. The Farmer’s Dog has a particular focus on eco-consciousness: their cardboard delivery boxes are recyclable, and the food insulation pack inside is not only compostable, but dissolvable: just run some water over it in your sink and it’ll melt right away! The food storage container is also biodegradable, and all of their materials are BPA-free and non-toxic. If you have a changing schedule or travel often, The Farmer’s Dog might be right for you: they make it easy to change your shipping address, frequency of deliveries, and amount of food ordered.   </p>
        
            <img class="nom_nom" src="https://static.insiderenvy.com/images/2021/06/29080747/Rectangle-18.jpg">
            <h2 class="nom_h">Darwin's</h2>
            <p class="sec10_cont">Some dog owners believe raw feeding is the healthiest option for their pet. If this sounds intriguing to you, we think Darwin’s Natural Pet Food is the best raw pet food delivery service around. Ordering from Darwin’s ensures your pet is getting fresh, safe, and contaminant-free raw food. With a high-quality mix of 75% meat to 25% vegetables, their food is full of nutrients and minimally processed. Options include chicken, duck, turkey, beef, and lamb. And, they offer free shipping!  </p>

            <img class="nom_nom" src="https://static.insiderenvy.com/images/2021/06/29080752/Rectangle-17-14.jpg">
            <h2 class="nom_h">Ollie</h2>
            <p class="sec10_cont">If you’re still not quite sure if you’re ready to make the switch to fresh dog food, Ollie is a great option to try. Not only do they offer 100% money-back guarantees on your first order, they also include custom instructions in every delivery to help you and your pet make a smooth transition to fresh food. We love the level of care Ollie has put into making sure that the switch to fresh food is as easy for owners as it is healthy for pets. Ollie’s fresh dog food contains absolutely no fillers: their meat-forward recipes also contain fruit, plant-based proteins, leafy greens and root vegetables to bulk up even more on vital nutrients. Their questionnaire makes sure your pet is matched with the right blend for their specific needs.   </p>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js Code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/fullpage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialization(){
        var myFullpage = new fullpage('#myContainer', {
            
            resize: true,
            animateAnchor:true,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            autoScrolling:true,
            responsive: 900,
            fitSection: true,
            
            navigation:true,
            continuousVertical:false,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            normalScrollElements: '#section10'
        });
    }


initialization();

</script>
```

What is wrong in the code I shared?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **normalScrollElements:** (default null) Demo If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the Javascript selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'). **This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.**

You can't apply `normalScrollElements` to a section.
Instead, you should be using the `scrollOverflow: true` option.

[ScrollOverflow example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#secondPage)

[ScrollOverflow example sourcecode](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrollOverflow.html)

Comment: your last suggestion helped a lot @Alvaro. I am facing one issue - after last section I have footer section and scroll to footer section is not working I think it is blocking browser scroll, can you please suggest how to make footer appear after last section.

Comment: Everything should be a section when using fullPage.js. Convert your footer into a section. And add the class `fp-auto-height` to it. See more about it on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Comment: Is fullpage.js license is mandatory to use @Alvaro, as I am getting license error in console.

Comment: Yes, unless you are using it for an open-source project compatible with GPLv3 license.